# Disorder: can't recognize who the voices belong to due to certain damage in the brain?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a person can't recognize faces due to some damage in the brain, it is called **prosopagnosia**.

When a person can't recognize colors due to some damage in the cerebral cortex, it is called **cerebral achromatopsia** (a type of color blindness, different from color blindess that is resulted by the abnormalities in the cells of the retina).

So is there a technical term for the disorder of not being able to recognize voices due to certain damage in the brain? [Can't know who is speaking just from hearing but do understand the content]

Comment: Some kind of [Amusia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amusia) ?

Comment: @mplungjan yeah I think so.

Comment: You might be interested in [cogsci.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inability to recognise sounds is [auditory agnosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_agnosia) of which *amusia* is a subset.

The auditory equivalent of prosopagnosia is [**phonagnosia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonagnosia):

> **Phonagnosia** is a type of agnosia, or loss of knowledge, that involves a disturbance in the recognition of familiar voices and the impairment of voice discrimination abilities. Phonagnosia is the auditory equivalent of Prosopagnosia.

Comment: Great answer! *Auditory agnosia* is a nice term to know. But sorry I was being ambiguous just now. I was actually looking for a term for the disorder of not being able to recognize who the voices belong to. I'm not sure if such disorder exists.. It is a bit like prosopagnosia, but instead of face perception, it is voice perception.

Comment: @Arch Found the right answer. My guess at echosagnosia wasn't too far off.